# Load data infile using .xls or .xlsx file

Tags: php, mysql

Right now im using this code to upload large csv files.

```
 $file_path = FCPATH.'uploads/master_listing/'.$file_name;

                $new_path = str_replace("\\", "/", $file_path);

                $this->db->query("LOAD DATA INFILE '".$new_path."' 
                    INTO TABLE fsi_temp_newmasterlist 
                    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                    IGNORE 1 LINES 
                    (SEQUENCENUMBER,NAME,ADDRESS,@PICKUPDATE,ENCODERNO,BARCODEVALUE,REMARKS,CLIENT,PROD)
                    SET MailpackID=NULL, PickUpDate=date_format(str_to_date(@PICKUPDATE, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d'), upload_unique_id=".$upload_unique_id.", UserID=".$this->session->userdata('fsi_user_id').", ProductID=".$product.", ClientID=".$client.", FileTypeID=".$file_type."
                ");
```

But I need also to upload excel files, like .xls and .xlsx

I've tried to upload .xls but its just return alot of characters..

Is there a way to upload .xls and .xlsx in LOAD DATA INFILE?

Is there a way to simplify my code to do this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no solution for how you want to do it, my best guess would be to use php excel https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ . and run queries on each of the rows to import the data.

Comment: @Gauthier Hmm I think It will take long time to upload large file..

Comment: You could try to convince your users to export the excel file to csv. Or you could show them how long it takes to convert the excel file to csv, then maybe they would start doing it on their own. I know its not a great answer, just an option.